# error passing a property to a function (name not defined)

Tags: python, properties

I am fairly new to python scripting, so getting into blender is a uphill battle at the moment. I want to pass a property into the REDO panel that, when checked, tells the operator to take effect only to the active object. But I keep getting an error message saying that the property is not defined (it is my understanding that it should be, because of the *self* argument in the function).
Any help is very much appreciated!

```
    "name": "Snap Origin to selected",
    "author": "Juan",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    #"location": "View3D > Mesh > Snap > Snap Origin to selected",
    "description": "snaps the origin of the object to a selection",
    "category": "Mesh",
}

import bpy

class MESH_OT_snapOrigin(bpy.types.Operator):
    """It has to begin with a selected element in edit mode"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.snap_origin_to_selected"
    bl_label = "Snap Origin to selected"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    only_active: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="set only active",
        description="set only the origin of the active object",
        default=False,
    )
    

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D'
    


    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
        if only_active.value is True:
           bpy.ops.objects.active.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
        else:
           bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
        # bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
        print("updated!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

# Registration

def set_origin_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        MESH_OT_snapOrigin.bl_idname,
        text="snap origin to selected",
        icon='PIVOT_CURSOR')
        
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_snapOrigin)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh.append(set_origin_button)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_snapOrigin)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh.remove(set_origin_button)
```

I also don't know if *bpy.ops.objects.active.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')* is going to work, given that I get an error before that, just so you know...it is probably also wrong.

Comment: You would have to use `self.only_active` to access the property and there is no need for a comparison with `True` you can simply write `if self.only_active`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot! The comparison part I had it like you say in the beggining, but trying to find the error I just add it at some point...just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so...I just had to add `self.` before the property for the function to recognize it (and lose the .value, since it is a boolean, but that's a different error). Like so:
`if self.only_active is True:`

I still don't know how to get the active object. The whole *context* part is particularly confusing to me. But I guess I'll get it eventually.